# React class name shows object

Tags: reactjs

I am working on project and I want to style my div but the class name show object when I inspect it.

```
  const style = {
    child: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundImage: `url(${banner2})`
    }
};
<div className={style.child}>
```

The output when I inspect it show

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: do JSON.stringify of your style,you shall see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are inserting a style object inside a className, that is not  a class name :

this might solve the issue if i guess right what you are trying to do:

```
 const style = {
    child: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundImage: `url(${banner2})`
    }
};
<div style={style.child}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be  passing an object as a className. You can pass it in the style prop

```
  const style = {
    child: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      backgroundImage: `url(${banner2})`
    }
 };
```